# How to have a common variable that auto increment in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

In my current Salesforce project, there are two main kinds: individual and organization. How to have a common variable that auto increment no matter either kind is created and count it?

Comment: This might be better to ask over at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think you could use list "Custom Setting" for this

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in comment using Custom Setting which would be incremented in a trigger would solve your problem.